# nginx rewrite causing facebook javascript not working

Tags: nginx, https, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my production server with SSL / https installed, my facebook **share** button is not showing.

The same share button is visible at my test server (http only) using the same code base.

I think this is caused by nginx redirect all traffic from http to https setting, however I'm not able to fix it

My facebook **share** button code base

```
<div id="fb_share_id" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.example.com/hi.html" data-type="button"></div> 

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.5'
});      
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

and my **nginx** rewrite rule

```
upstream example_app_server {
server unix:/webapps/example/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {


listen 443 default_server ssl;
server_name example.com;
server_name www.example.com;
ssl on; 
.
.
}
```

Comment: A few ideas: 1) change the data-href link to also use https 2) make sure the facebook sdk gets loaded (view the network tab of your browsers dev tools) 3) look for errors in the browser console and post them here

Comment: 99% that this is not related to nginx since it all happens in JS and JS goes to FB directly. As the comment above mentioned, check out the console, see if there are errors. For instance – wrong Facebook app ID; JavaScript error somewhere else in the code that breaks all JS on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving both `www.example.com` and `example.com` domains in `server_name` directive it has no sense you perform the *www.* to *non-www.* redirection, just remove this rewrite rule:

```
# This is NO NEEDED, as long as your server ALSO process www.example.com as server_name
# server {
#   server_name www.example.com;
#   return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
#}

server {


  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com; # PUT both domains into unique directive
  requests arrives
  ssl on; 
  .
  .
}
```

Otherwise, in case you actually want to redirect all *www.* uris to *non-www.* uris then just change `data-href="http://example.com/hi.html"` on your html and change `server_name` directive:

```
server {


  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  # server_name www.example.com; # This is NO NEEDED, only example.com requests arrives
  ssl on; 
  .
  .
}
```